# Default MasterPage its wrong, its takes from another web application

Tags: sharepoint

Im workin with SP2010 and I create new web application in the central, I have 5 more in this central but the problem is when I try to loggin with new webApplication because it takes by default another master page from another webapplication, this master page is not set in site collection by default or in the code.

Some ideas?

thx

Comment: A master page cannot be fetched outside of it's own web application. You're barking up the wrong tree I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

In the 14 hive for your SharePoint server, check 14\TEMPLATE\GLOBAL\v4.master. Compare that file to a known clean install of SharePoint. It is possible that someone modified the file directly on the web server rather than creating an unghosted version within a site collection. This would cause a newly created web applications to use a version of a master page from another web application.

Comment: Thanks for your help!, now I have another problem, I create custom login.aspx for SharePoint 2010 and it takes by default master page from another webapplication, I go to site settings and configure properly the master page system and custom master page but when I try to charge login.aspx the master page from another WebApplication  is here.